# Automatically reset value on the fly

Tags: javascript

I try to reset a value when it goes to 0.
so I added this on top of my code but it doesn't seems to work :

```
if (gameData.monster_hp <= 0) {
  gameData.monster_hp = 100;
}
```

And here here my whole code :

```js
var gameData = {
  player_hp: 0,
  monster_hp: 100,
  hit_dmg: 5,
  atk_speed_ratio: 4,
}


if (gameData.monster_hp <= 0) {
  gameData.monster_hp = 100;
}


function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

function hit() {
  gameData.monster_hp -= gameData.hit_dmg
  document.getElementById("monster_hp").innerHTML = gameData.monster_hp + "HP"
}
async function auto_hit() {
  while (gameData.monster_hp > 0) {
    hit();
    s = 1000 / gameData.atk_speed_ratio,
      await sleep(s);
  }
}

function dmg_up(n) {
  gameData.hit_dmg = gameData.hit_dmg + n;
  console.log(gameData.hit_dmg);
}

function atkspeed_up(n) {
  gameData.atk_speed_ratio = gameData.atk_speed_ratio + n;
  console.log(gameData.atk_speed_ratio);
}
```

Comment: Of course this has no effect in _that_ place - you did just _set_ the value a couple of lines before, and _nothing_ has changed it in the meantime.

Comment: Your test is outside a function so will be evaluated only once, just after variable declaration, so without any effect.

Comment: I made you a snippet. You can click edit, then scroll down and click "edit above snippet" and add relevante HTML and CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put

```
if (gameData.monster_hp <= 0) {
  gameData.monster_hp = 100;
}
```

inside a function named `checkScore`. Then, whenever you make a change to `gameData.monster_hp`, you can call the function `checkScore`.

Answer (score 0):

Its very hard to understand your problem from this code. You should add a runnable snippet which will demonstrate your problem but by looking at your code, you can put your check in `hit` function

Like this

```
function hit() {
  gameData.monster_hp -= gameData.hit_dmg
  document.getElementById("monster_hp").innerHTML = gameData.monster_hp + "HP"
  if (gameData.monster_hp <= 0) {
     gameData.monster_hp = 100;
  }
}
```